# How to calculate derivative under area integral

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

I have a function which is defined as
\begin{equation}
P(x_i,y_i)=\iint_{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2\leq\delta}f(x,y,x_i,y_i) \, dx \, dy.
\end{equation}
How to calculate the derivative with respective $x_i$? Is it enough to write
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P(x_i,y_i)}{\partial x_i}=\iint_{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2 \leq \delta} \frac{\partial f(x,y,x_i,y_i)}{\partial x_i} \, dx\,dy.
\end{equation}

Since the boundary is also a function of $x_{i}$, do we have to add another term like the Leibniz rule for differentiating an integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enforcing the substitution $\xi=x-x_i$ and $\eta =y-y_i$, we have

$$P(x_i,y_i)=\underbrace{\iint_{\xi^2+\eta^2\le \delta^2}}_{\text{Independent of}\,x_i,y_i}f(\underbrace{\xi+x_i,\eta+y_i}_{\text{Dependent on}\,x_i,y_i},x_i,y_i)\,d\xi\,d\eta$$

Differentiating with respect to $x_i$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P(x_i,y_i)}{\partial x_i}&=\iint_{\xi^2+\eta^2\le \delta^2}\left(f_1(\xi+x_i,\eta+y_i,x_i,y_i)+f_3(\xi+x_i,\eta+y_i,x_i,y_i)\right)\,d\xi\,d\eta\\\\
&=\iint_{\xi^2+\eta^2\le \delta^2} \frac{\partial f(\xi+x_i,\eta+y_i,x_i,y_i)}{\partial \xi}\,d\xi\,d\eta\\\\
&+\iint_{\xi^2+\eta^2\le \delta^2}f_3(\xi+x_i,\eta+y_i,x_i,y_i)\,d\xi\,d\eta\\\\
&=\underbrace{\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \left(f\left(x_i+\sqrt{\delta^2-\eta^2},\eta+y_i,x_i,y_i\right)-f\left(x_i-\sqrt{\delta^2-\eta^2},\eta+y_i,x_i,y_i\right)\right)\,d\eta}_{\text{"Boundary Term"}}\\\\
&+\iint_{\xi^2+\eta^2\le \delta^2}f_3(\xi+x_i,\eta+y_i,x_i,y_i)\,d\xi\,d\eta
\end{align}$$

Now, finish by carrying out the inner integral of the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.

---

Alternatively, we can write the original integral as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P(x_i,y_i)}{\partial x_i}&=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\int_{y_i-\delta}^{y_i+\delta}\int_{x_i-\sqrt{\delta^2-(y-y_i)^2}}^{x_i+\sqrt{\delta^2-(y-y_i)^2}}f(x,y,x_i,y_i)\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=\int_{y_i-\delta}^{y_i+\delta} \left( f\left(x_i+\sqrt{\delta^2-(y-y_i)^2},y,x_i,y_i\right)-f\left(x_i-\sqrt{\delta^2-(y-y_i)^2},y,x_i,y_i\right) \right)\,dy\\\\
&+\iint_{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2\le \delta^2}\frac{\partial f(x,y,x_i,y_i)}{\partial x_i}\,dx\,dy
\end{align}$$

Comment: I did not see the essential difference after the variable change.

Comment: There is a missing term in the OP; the OP only has the term $f_3$.  I've edited to provide details.  Let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: $f_3$ is the partial derivative with respect to the third variable.  Note that after the change of variables, both the first and third variables depend on $x_i$.

Comment: I edit the OP. I want to know if the partial derivative has any relationship with the boundary. Even after the variable change, the boundary is still a function of $x_{i}$.

Comment: After the change of variables, the limits do not depend on $x_i$ and $y_i$.  That is one rationale for enforcing the substitution.

Comment: @user125056 That is a false statement.  After the variable change, the limits are independent of $x_i$ and $y_i$, but the integrand is most certainly a function of both.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it without variable change? I get confused by the change of variable. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've added an alternative way forward that does not change variables.